# Hotwiring a Bluetooth speaker into a Bluetooth receiver

Tags: bluetooth, receiver, headphones

New here. So I have this mini Bluetooth speaker I bought a few years ago. Fast forward to now, and I've upgraded from it. Was going through a junk box and found it again, and wondered if I could just cut the wires to the speakers and resolder them to a headphone jack, to create a Bluetooth receiver for my non-bluetooth headset. It should be easy, I just am worried about one thing: the preamp is designed for speaker volumes, not headphones volumes. It is a mini speaker, and it's maximum volume is only a fraction of my newer speaker, but even still I'd rather not run the risk of blowing my headphones. I tried searching online but all I could find was people hotwiring Bluetooth headsets instead of Bluetooth speakers.
Should I be worried about this? Should I slap a resistor onto the ground? If so, how much resistance should I use?

Comment: Like @Wilfred said, messure it. Play a 50 Hz "song" at full volume and messure the output with a multimeter. I would suspect you will see a few volt AC and that "needs" to be divided down a bit/not play at full volume.

Answer (score 1):

if I were you, I would measure the voltages from both your headphones and bluetooth speaker. Most often, a 3.5 mm jack (female connector) output voltage is around 1 Volts. Make sure that the maximum output voltage of your bluetooth system is the same as the maximum output voltage of a 3.5 mm jack. Nothing can go wrong then, I believe. I don't think that (difference in) resistance of the two speakers is important.
Maybe the right output voltage of your bluetooth system is achieved when leaving the pre-amp. I do not have experience with that.
I hope I helped you with this.